# Fade In On Scroll

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll, fadein

I've got this code below which enables a fade in on scroll animation for various content and imagery on my website, however I'd like to modify it slightly.

Some of the images are larger than the screen height and so they don't fade in until the entire image has been scrolled past. Instead I'd like for everything to fade in perhaps just after the element has become visible from the top of the screen, how could the code be modified to accomplish this?

```
$('.site-content h1, .site-content h2, .site-content h3, .site-content h4,  .site-content .left_right_panels_wrapper img,  .site-content .left_right_panels_wrapper .bg_image, .site-content .box_button, .site-content p, .site-content ul li').addClass('hideme');
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){
    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
        }
    }); 
});
$(window).scroll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are comparing it to the bottom of the object, a simple change

You have this
`var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();`

You can just change it to
`var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top`
That way you get the top of the element

You're now comparing it to the top of the element, rather than the bottom of it

Now you might want to change the variable name but that's up to you

Comment: This is what I was after! If I wanted it to appear let's say 200px from the top how would I do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: You simply add 200 to `bottom_of_object` (which is now the top I kept the name to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the element to fade in when it's top reaches the top of the window, instead of when the bottom passes the bottom of the window, correct?

If so, simply doing this should work:

```js
var threshold = 200;

$('.hideme').each( function(){
    var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top;
    var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
    /* If the object reaches the top of the window, fade it it */
    if( top_of_window + threshold >= top_of_object ){
         $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
    }
```

Change the value of threshold to make it show higher or lower in the page.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me? Although I think you're on the right track as I do want a threshold so that items fadein X amount of pixels after the top of the screen passes the top of the element. - https://pastebin.com/JtJdNXX8